# Why WP_Query is giving wrong output for custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

My query shows everything including default `posts`, `cardguide` and other custom post type posts.

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type'     => 'cardguide',
    'taxonomy'      => 'post_tag',
    'tag_id'        => $tag_id, // an integer let's say.. 27
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'orderby'       => 'id',
    'order'         => 'DESC',

);
$my_query = new Wp_query( $args );
```

^ But this should output only a list of `cardguide` type posts.

So I tried this one below using `pre_get_posts` hook. And shows the correct result.

```
$args  = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'post_tag',
    'tag_id'        => $tag_id,
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'orderby'       => 'id',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
);

// filtering only 'Card Guides' for grid view
function only_card_guides( $wp_query ) {
    $wp_query->set('post_type', 'cardguide');
} add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'only_card_guides');

$my_query = new Wp_query( $args );
```

#### Expected workaround

My problem with this second method is, when using `pre_get_posts`, my footer of the theme got broken. I guess the default query got modified and does that mess.

Is there any way to reset the query back to it's previous stage? Let's say if I can save the previous state somewhere or something like that?

#### Need solution

In the first method, why the query is not working. Am I missing something there? Looking at the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), I can say I'm pretty much doing the same thing as shown there.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata();` try using this? sometimes it picks previously set post data..

Comment: @Coderanonymous, tried this one. Same thing as before. No luck. :(

Comment: Can you elaborate on first example (without filter)? Post some code before and after it? In which file you have put it? The code itself is good, so I guess that problem is elsewhere. Also, if you are going to use `WP_Query` directly, you should have good understanding of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), especially topic of multiple loops (caution: I find this piece of Codex documentation very poorly written). If your case is simple enough, you should be able to get away with `get_posts()` call (it returns array for you to loop over).